# About $ AGL(1,16)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I wanted to know orders of all subgroups of the group $AGL(1,16)$ (of order 240). Indeed,  regarding to
the problem mentioned in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143229/a-question-about-finite-groups-a-weak-version-of-the-converse-of-lagrange-theor, we are looking for the smallest group(s) which does not have the property.

***** Now, is it true that there exist subsets $A$, $B$ of $AGL(1,16)$  such that
$|A|=6$, $|B|=40$ [resp. $|A|=10$, $|B|=24$]  and $AGL(1,16)=AB$?

Comment: Of course, your answer is complete for $AGL(1,16)$. Do you have any idea for groups $G$ with orders between 191 and 240 (the problem in mathoverflow)?  What about the second part of the question?

Comment: Can you not do it yourself in GAP? I am afraid I don't know how to test whether a group is a product of sets that are not necessarily subgroups.

Comment: I'm not familiar to the GAP. For product of subsets please see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177747/factorization-of-a-finite-group-by-two-subsets/177797#177797 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the answer in GAP or Magma with a few seconds typing. It is $$\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 12, 15, 16, 48, 80, 240 \}.$$

So there are no subgroups of orders $6, 10, 20, 24, 30, 40, 60, 120$. But you should be able to prove that yourself!